# Cannot get onserverclick to work

Tags: asp.net

Here's what is in my .aspx:

```
<div><input id="testButton" type="image" src="<%=TestImageUrl %>" onserverclick="RedirectTest" /></div>
```

And in my code-behind this:

```
protected void RedirectTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Logic is here
}
```

It's not hitting my method at all when I click the image.  And  please note, I do not want to use an ImageButton.  I want to figure out how to get this working with a plain old input tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're missing the runat="server" attribute on the input tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `runat='server'` to the input's definition

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `runat="server"` attribute to your input tag.